# How do I get my code to not worry about capitalization?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How do I make it so the code can read the user input regardless of capitalization?

```
def answer_question(df, column_name, question):
    if column_name not in df.columns:
        return "Data invalid"
    else:
        if question == "average":
            return df[column_name].mean()
        elif question == "minimum":
            return df[column_name].min()
        elif question == "maximum":
            return df[column_name].max()
        elif question == "standard deviation":
            return df[column_name].std()
        else:
            return "Sorry, I don't understand your question."

file_path = "filepath.csv"

df = read_csv(file_path)
column_name = input("What is the column name?: ")

print("what function would you like to preform?: ")
question = input().lower()

answer = answer_question(df, column_name, question)
print(answer)
```

Trying to get the code to not worry about capitalization.

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting on the post, I am new to coding.

Comment: You could try `question.lower()` to format all capital letters to lower letters. See [this introduction](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-string-methods/python-string-lower/).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to perform non-case-sensitive string comparison in any language is to make sure the strings are already cast in the same format.

It can be uppercase or lowercase.

For example,

`if question.lower() == "average":`

or

`if question.upper() == "AVERAGE":`

or

`if question.upper() == "average".upper():`

A more language-specific way in Python is to use [casefold()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold). This will only work if you're using Python 3.3 or higher.

Comment: Looking at your re-formatted code, you might also want to make sure your column names correspond in every conditional. 
To make the column names array all lowercase, `if column_name not in df.columns.str.lower():` on line 2 of your code.  
Check your code to make sure all string comparisons are consistent. Good luck!